# Хранение в памяти много изображений

Tags: javascript, jquery

Задача состоит вот в чем. 
Есть сайт с элементами меню, каждый элемент подгружает что-то одно:

- Секвенции (Например моделька 360 состоящая из набора фотографий)
- Видео
- Просто картинка

**Не напрягая лишним функционалом, просто сведу к минимуму:** 
Есть кнопка при какой необходимо, чтобы все секвенции, картинки или даже видео подгружались в памяти и при воспроизведении не глючили.

Какие самые благоприятные варианты реализовать это без лагов?

Буду рад любой помощи.

---

Реализовал загрузку всех изображений в кэш, лаги всё равно есть. Поэтому уже обратился сюда.

Код загрузки изображений в кэш:

```
!function ($) {
/**
 * В поданный на вход элемент создается div, куда будут помещены изображения.
 * Данную функцию вызывает массив, в каком содержаться пути к изображениям.
 * @param el Элемент, куда будет помещен блок с кэшем
 * @param id Уникальное имя для блока с кэшем
 */
$.fn.preload = function (el, id) {
    // Если элемента с указанным идентификатором не существует, то загружаем в кэш
    if (!el.find('#' + id).exists()) {
        // Формируем блок, где будут лежать указанные изображения
        $("<div class='images_cache' id='" + id + "'></div>").hide().appendTo(el);
        // Проходим каждый элемент массива и формируем изображение
        this.each(function () {
            $('<img/>').attr("src", this).appendTo("#" + id);
        });
    }
};
}(window.jQuery);


/**
 * Загрузка переданного элемента в кэш (Осуществляет загрузку секвенций и картинок)
 * @param el Dom-element
 * @param index Индекс массива
 */
function preload_item(el, index) {
    var id = el.attr('data-id'), // Указанный идентификатор для элемента
        src, // Тут будет храниться путь к картинке
        frames, // Кол-во фреймов, какие будут записаны в кэш
        arr = [], // Массив, в каком будет храниться путь к каждому изображению
        img_name, // Будет храниться только имя изображения с удаленным постфиксом 
        directory; // Будет храниться папка, в какой будут все изображения

    // Определяем тип контента, если секвенции, то много изображений, иначе одно изображение
    switch (el.attr('data-content')) {
        case 'sequence':
            src = el.attr("data-path");
            frames = parseInt(el.attr('data-frames'));

            // Записываем каждый путь к фрейму, для записи в кэш
            for (var i = 1; i < frames + 1; i++) {
                img_name = src.split('/')[src.split('/').length - 1];
                directory = src.split('/').slice(0, -1).join("/");
                arr.push(directory + "/" + img_name.split('_')[0] + "_" + i + "." + img_name.split('.')[1])
            }
            // Записываем в кэш и передаем элемент в каком будет содержаться images_cache и уникальное имя для него
            $(arr).preload(content, img_name.split('_')[0] + id);
            break;
        case 'image':
            // Костыль небольшой.
            // Получаем путь к изображению где лежать с мал. разрешением и заменяем на папку, где лежать с большим разрешением.
            src = el.find('img').attr("src").replace('colors_small', 'colors_big');

            // Формируем путь к изображению
            img_name = src.split('/')[src.split('/').length - 1];
            directory = src.split('/').slice(0, -1).join("/");
            arr.push(directory + "/" + img_name);

            // Записываем в кэш и передаем те же данные
            $(arr).preload(content, img_name.split('.')[0] + id);
            break;
    }

    // Получаем список все img, какие не успели загрузиться
    var images_not_loaded = $(".images_cache > img").not(function () {
        return this.complete;
    });

    var count = images_not_loaded.length;

    // Если кол-во > 0
    if (count) {
        // Записываем их
        images_not_loaded.load(function () {
            count--;
            // Если уже нечего записывать и "левая переменная"
            if (!count && index === ids.length - 1 && startAnimate) {
                // Что-то делаем
            }
        });
    } else {
        // Если уже нечего записывать и "левая переменная"
        if (index === ids.length - 1 && startAnimate) {
            // Что-то делаем
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Есть вариант выводить то, что ты там хочешь, ПОСЛЕ того, как оно загрузится полностью в кеш. Это легко реализуемо и всё такое, но нужно ли оно тебе, ведь до полной загрузки может пройти неравное количество времени. В таком случае в плане UX/UI нужно лепить анимацию загрузки контента и всё такое. Стандартная практика.

Comment: @VostokSisters, я изначально реализовал через кэш, но с такой реализацией лаги всё равно имеются. Поэтому я уже написал сюда, в поисках более оптимального варианта. С помощью UX/Ui загрузку контента я не делал, чисто влипил анимацию на css.

Comment: Черт знает как ты там что реализовывал. Без кода всё равно не ясно ничего. Хотя бы на дивах показал бы, что там как у тебя оптимизируется в плане производительности. В таком случае ничего нельзя больше посоветовать или подсказать.

Comment: @VostokSisters, я добавил код, надеюсь это поможет.

Comment: О-о-ох, как сложно разбирать чужой js (: А можешь тогда создашь запускаемый сниппет с парой примеров-изображений? Вроде не должно быть сложным, но уже прям будет понятно, куда копать.

Comment: @VostokSisters, я добавил комментарии. Если всё равно понадобиться сниппет, ладно уж сделаю;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Загружайте изображения через new Image();
.src даст вам путь.
.onload создаст событие окончания загрузки - потом устанавливайте в требуемый вам div.

Как полагаю, часть проблем у вас от того, что вы все добавляете в DOM, что также нагружает браузер.

Как пример, используйте вот такой вариант:

```
var images = {}; // Массив изображений

function preload(el){
    var id = el.attr('data-id');
    var content = el.attr('data-content');

    var obj = {
        loaded: 0,
        images: []
    };
    var src = el.attr('data-path');
    /// тут непонятно как вы генерируете пути
    var arr = (content === 'sequence') ? getImageUrlsFromSequenceData() : getImageUrlsFromImageData();
    /// но предположим в конце у нас их будет массив arr
    arr.forEach(function(item){
        //создаем элемент Image
        var image = new Image();
        //устанавливаем событие для получения того, что оно загрузилось 
        //количество незагруженных вы можете получить через obj.images.length-obj.loaded
        image.onLoad=getActionOnLoad(obj);
        //назначаем урл
        image.src=item;
        //добавляем в массив
        obj.images.push(image);
    });
    //добавляем в ссылочный массив
    images[id] = obj;
}

function getActionOnLoad(obj){
    return (function(){
        obj.loaded++;
        //тут еще можно вызывать требуемый нам каллбек, если loaded
        //достигло images.length. его можно добавить в параметры прелоадера
    });
}

function getImageUrlsFromSequenceData(data){
    //тут вы генерируете ссылки для sequence
    return [];
}
function getImageUrlsFromImageData(data){
    //тут вы генерируете ссылки для Image
    return [];
}
```